# How to stop google map from shifting to center

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this set of codes and it works, however everytime I click on my button to get my current location, it will position my map to center. Is it possible to get my location WHILE not moving my map?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlText, 'click', function(self) 
{
    getLocation(self);
});

function getLocation(self)
{
    console.log("in get location", self);
    let locationOptions = 
    {
        timeout             : 60000, 
        enableHighAccuracy  : true
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
    (
        (position) => 
        {
            self.curLat     = position.coords.latitude;
            self.curLong    = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log("updated position coord:"+self.curLat+","+self.curLong);
            self.local      = new Storage(LocalStorage);
            self.local.set("currLong", self.curLong);
            self.local.set("currLat", self.curLat);

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(self.curLat, self.curLong));
            markers         = removeMarker(markers);
            addMarker(map, markers);
        },
        (error) => {console.log(error);}, locationOptions
    );
};

myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker
({
    map         : map,
    icon        : image,
    animation   : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position    : map.getCenter(),
    id          : 'myLocationMarker'
});

markers.push(myLocationMarker);
```

---

I have solve my issue by changing

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(self.curLat, self.curLong));
     to
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(self.curLat, self.curLong);
```

and passing the data to addMarker to use it for position.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `position: map.getCenter()` property from the object you pass to google.maps.Marker ?

Comment: Hello, I have solve this issue by removing map.setCenter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(self.curLat, self.curLong));
```